# Get posts from friends (that you have permission to see)

Tags: sql, database, performance, join

I want to get all the posts from the user's friends, but only the ones that he has the permission to see. I have the following tables in my database (only the relevant attributes are included):

**User:**

```
userid
```

**Post**

```
postid    authorid
```

**Friendship**

```
friendshipid    userid    friendid
```

**Permission**

```
postid    userid
```

Each friendship has 2 records in the table **Friendship** (if users 1 and 2 are friends, there will be 1 2 and 2 1 added to the table). Each post has multiple records in the **Permission** table, userid in this tables means the user that has the permission to see the post (it does not mean that this user is the author of the post). This user has to be friend of the author of the post.

What would be the best query to get my results with good performance? Also could I achieve better performance if I add authorid to the table **Permission**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get all posts where `@UserId`'s friends are authors and where `@UserId` has permission to see the post:

```
SELECT postid
FROM Post
INNER JOIN Friendship ON Friendship.userid = @UserId AND Post.authorid = Friendship.friendid
INNER JOIN Permission ON Post.postid = Permission.postid AND Permission.userid = @UserId
```

Note that performance is contingent on things outside the query, such as indices, but this should be an efficient query.

Comment: there is a problem in your query what if there is only one entry of persons being friends lets say either 1 and 2 or 2 and 1 what will you do then ?? can you help ??